# Will ubuntu erase all my harddisks upon installation

Tags: installation, partitioning, hard-drive

I have 2 harddrives, 2 SSD's stripped and 1 HDD (got it configurerd with windows when I bought this laptop). I want to install my Ubuntu on my SSD's RAID where currently Windows is installed. But when I click "erase" in the Ubuntu installer and select the SSD's RAID volume, will it also erase my other HDD? Because I have saved all my important files on this HDD, so it must not got erased..

I'm 99% sure it doesn't, but because of the important files I must know it for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure, then remove the other drive. If you can't, then do backups. Either way, it should confirm with you what drives/partitions are being removed/changed/added, if the feedback is correct, there you go, if it's not, then try using "Something else".

So, the real question here is: do the installer (ubiquity) will remove what is not supposed to remove?

The answer is: it removes what you tell him to remove and it ask you to confirm.

Comment: The problem is, I can't remove the harddrive because it's within my laptop and the other thing is that it's to much to backup on my external drive.

Comment: Ok, I gave you two solutions so you don't have to worry about "possible phantoms" mistakes. If you are 99% sure that Ubuntu won't remove your stuff, just install it, if you see something weird in the feedback then stop and check were the problem is.